# What is the React Hooks way of handling multiple actions while also setting state?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I have 4 components: `App, CatalogList, CatalogPreview, CatalogDetail`

`App` is the parent component and I have these state values:

```
const [catalog, setCatalog] = useState({ id: 1, name: 'Electronics' })
const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false)
```

`CatalogList` and `CatalogPreview` components receive the above state values as props along with their setter functions.

Inside `CatalogList.js`:

I have a list of catalog links (electronics, furniture, ...) that when you click on one of them,

it opens up the `CatalogPreview` modal. Inside the modal, there's an *'Explore'* button.

When you click the *'Explore'* button, it needs to do 4 things:

set the selected catalog in state (in App.js)
save selected catalog in localStorage
navigate to the detail page
close the modal window

I attempted the following in the *'Explore'* button's click handler (Inside the modal):

```
function explore() {
  props.setCatalog({...})
  props.setIsModalOpen(false)
  window.localStorage.setItem('catalog', JSON.stringify({...})
  history.push('detail-route') // this brings up the CatalogDetail
}
```

[Link to Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-sanderson-r2i0l?file=/src/App.js)

Questions:

1. Is this the correct way?
2. In the `CatalogDetail` component, if I click a Delete button and make a delete API request,
    how do I navigate back to the `CatalogList` route **AFTER** the call is completed.

Comment: It's not necessarily incorrect, though IMHO it could be improved. If you could update your question to include a full [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of each component I think I could better make suggestions.

Comment: @DrewReese added link to a code sandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Instead of storing the modal open/close state in the parent `App` component it should be demoted to the child `CatalogList` component that is managing the modal.
2. Move the persisting to localStorage to a `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the `catalog` state. When the state updates, persist it to localStorage.
3. Create a `updateCatalog` callback function to accept a new value to update the catalog state with. Pass this to `CatalogList`.
4. The `explore` callback should be promoted/lifted up to the `CatalogList` component.  This allows `CatalogPreview` to basically just render the modal. `explore` still calls to update the catalog data, close the modal, and navigate.

   App

   ```
   function App() {
     const [catalog, setCatalog] = useState({ id: 1, name: "Electronics" });

     useEffect(() => {
       window.localStorage.setItem("catalog", JSON.stringify(catalog));
     }, [catalog]);

     const updateCatalog = value => {
       setCatalog( ...value... );
     };

     return (
       <Switch>
         <Route exact path="/">
           <CatalogList updateCatalog={updateCatalog} />
         </Route>
         <Route exact path="/detail">
           <CatalogDetail catalog={catalog} />
         </Route>
       </Switch>
     );
   }
   ```

   CatalogList

   ```
   function CatalogList(props) {
     const history = useHistory();

     const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
     const catalogs = [
       { id: 1, name: "Electronics" },
       { id: 2, name: "Furniture & Appliances" },
       { id: 3, name: "Sports & Outdoors" }
     ];

     const openPreview = () => {
       setIsOpen(true);
     };

     function explore() {
       props.updateCatalog(... some new value ...);
       setIsOpen(false);
       history.push("/detail");
     }

     return (
       <div>
         Available catalogs
         <ul>
           {catalogs.map((c, index) => (
             <li key={c.id} onClick={() => openPreview(c.id)} className="link">
               {c.name}
             </li>
           ))}
         </ul>
         <CatalogPreview isOpen={isOpen} onExplore={explore} />
       </div>
     );
   }
   ```

   CatalogPreview

   ```
   function CatalogPreview(props) {
     return (
       <Modal show={props.isOpen}>
         <Modal.Header closeButton>
           <Modal.Title>Catalog Preview</Modal.Title>
         </Modal.Header>
         <Modal.Footer>
           <Button variant="primary" onClick={props.onExplore}>
             Explore
           </Button>
         </Modal.Footer>
       </Modal>
     );
   }
   ```
5. Use `useHistory` and update the `onClick` handler to navigate back to the home page.

   ```
   function CatalogDetail(props) {
     const history = useHistory();

     return (
       <div>
         <p>Detail Page</p>
         <button
           onClick={() => {
             // Make API call then navigate home
             history.push("/");
           }}
         >
           DELETE
         </button>
       </div>
     );
   }
   ```

## Demo

[image: Edit what-is-the-react-hooks-way-of-handling-multiple-actions-while-also-setting-stat]